# Растягивание рисунка вместе с окном в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Как реализовать в Tkinter растягивание рисунка на компоненте Canvas при растягивании окна?

Answer (score 2):

... цитирую "Фрейм для размещения кнопок операций. Нужен для управления растягиванием при изменении размеров окна – весь фрейм будет «привязан» к нижней кромке окна

```
comf = Frame(tk)
comf.pack(fill=X)
```

"